# -- No package 'glfw3' found on Windows 10

Tags: cmake, makefile, build, glfw, cmake-modules

```
C:\mangetsu\build>cmake -DBUILD_GUI=On ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30146.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30146.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "0.26")
-- Checking for module 'glfw3'
--   No package 'glfw3' found
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:607 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:829 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (pkg_check_modules)
```

I tried to install it, but cmake doesn't seem to find it.

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential cmake zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
```

```
sudo apt install -y libopengl-dev libglfw3-dev
```

I'm trying to build a "program" using cmake, but I'm having problems since it can't find the necessary packages, even though I already have them installed.

The problem is that it only teaches how to install on linux, but on windows I had to do it manually.

The cmake lists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(mangetsu LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/;/usr/local/")

if ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
  message(SEND_ERROR "In-source builds are not allowed.")
endif ()

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -gdwarf-4 -g3 -g -rdynamic")
  set(GCC_OPTIMIZATION "-O0")
endif ()

set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Werror -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=pragmas -Wno-error=unused-local-typedefs")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${GCC_OPTIMIZATION}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-omit-frame-pointer")

# Put UI stuff behind a build flag so that people don't have to mess around
# with deps as much by default
if (${BUILD_GUI})
  # OpenGL
  include(FindOpenGL)
  include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

  # Glfw for windowing
  find_package(PkgConfig)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
  pkg_check_modules(PC_LIBGLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
  include_directories(${PC_LIBGLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

include_directories(include)

# Json library
include_directories(vendor/json)

# Only build imgui lib if UI is enabled
if (${BUILD_GUI})
  include_directories(vendor/imgui/)
  add_library(imgui
      STATIC
      vendor/imgui/imgui.cpp
      vendor/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp
      vendor/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp
      vendor/imgui/imgui_impl_opengl2.cpp
      vendor/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp
      vendor/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp
  )
  set_target_properties(imgui
      PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
  )
  target_link_libraries(imgui
     ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
     ${PC_LIBGLFW_LIBRARIES}
  )
endif()

add_library(mg_util
  src/util/fs.cpp
)

add_library(mg_data
  src/data/mzp.cpp
  src/data/mzx.cpp
  src/data/mrg.cpp
  src/data/nam.cpp
  src/data/nxx.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mg_data
    z
    mg_util
)

add_executable(nxx_decompress
    src/tools/nxx_decompress.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(nxx_decompress
    mg_data
)

add_executable(nxgx_compress
    src/tools/nxgx_compress.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(nxgx_compress
    mg_data
)

add_executable(mzx_decompress
    src/tools/mzx_decompress.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mzx_decompress
    mg_data
)

add_executable(mzx_compress
    src/tools/mzx_compress.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mzx_compress
    mg_data
)

add_executable(mzp_info
    src/tools/mzp_info.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mzp_info
    mg_data
)

add_executable(mzp_extract
    src/tools/mzp_extract.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mzp_extract
    mg_data
    stdc++fs
)

add_executable(mzp_compress
    src/tools/mzp_compress.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mzp_compress
    mg_data
)

add_executable(nam_read
    src/tools/nam_read.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(nam_read
    mg_data
)

if (${BUILD_GUI})
  add_executable(data_explorer
      src/tools/data_explorer.cpp
  )
  target_link_libraries(data_explorer
      mg_data
      imgui
  )
endif()

add_executable(script_text_to_content_json
    src/tools/script_text_to_content_json.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(script_text_to_content_json
    mg_data
    ssl
    crypto
)

add_executable(repack_script_text_translation
    src/tools/repack_script_text_translation.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(repack_script_text_translation
    mg_data
    ssl
    crypto
)

add_executable(mrg_extract
    src/tools/mrg_extract.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mrg_extract
    mg_data
    stdc++fs
)

add_executable(mrg_pack
    src/tools/mrg_pack.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mrg_pack
    mg_data
    stdc++fs
)

add_executable(mrg_info
    src/tools/mrg_info.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mrg_info
    mg_data
    stdc++fs
)

add_executable(mrg_replace
    src/tools/mrg_replace.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mrg_replace
    mg_data
    stdc++fs
)
```

Comment: Edit your question in order to provide additional informations: how did you build glfw? Did you install it properly? How do you call CMake configuration exactly? Which arguments? What is CMakeLists content? Basically a rule of thumb when you call CMake configuration is to populate `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` with install locations of project dependencies, so that `find_*` like CMake commands can find dependencies on your file system.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you show `sudo apt install` commands. According to your CMakeLists, you want to compile with msvc. Are you trying to install dependencies under WSL? If that's the case, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I edited and put the contents of the file cmakelists.txt, as you asked.
And I put in the sudo commands because those were the only commands they gave to install glfw3.
I used pre-compiled binaries for glfw3, but cmake couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, tarballs available on https://www.glfw.org/download.html for Windows don't contain pkgconfig & CMake config files. In a sense these packages are illformed.

I advice to build & install glfw from source or use a package manager (conan or vcpkg for example on Windows).

Then in your CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
[...]
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE glfw)
```

CMake configuration:

```shell
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<install/path/of/glfw>
```

PS: your CMakeLists has many more issues unrelated to your question (non-portable way to do several things: compile flags specific to gcc, fragile link to hardcoded unix lib names of zlib & openssl, link to stdc++fs while it doesn't make sense and can't work for many compilers, an absolute path hardcoded in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH).